# BNF assign string literal to a variable

Tags: compilation, context-free-grammar, bnf

I am trying to write some BNF (not EBNF) to describe the various elements of the following code fragment which is in no particular programming language but would be syntactically correct in VBA.

```
If Temperature <=0 Then
   Description = "Freezing"
End If
```

So far I have come up with the BNF at the bottom of this post (I have not yet described string, number or identifier).

What perplexes me is the second line of code, Description = "Freezing", in which I am assigning a string literal to an identifier.  How should I deal with this in my BNF?

I am tempted to simply adjust my definition of a factor like this...

```
<factor> ::= <identifier> | <number> | <string_literal> | (<expression)>
```

...after all, in VBA an arithmetic expression containing a string or a string variable would be syntactically correct and not picked up until run time. For example (4+3)*(6-"hi") would not be picked up as a syntax error.  Is this the right approach?

Or should I leave the production for a factor as it is and redefine the assignment like this...?

```
<assignment> ::= <identifier> = <expression> | <identifier> = <string_literal>
```

I am not trying to define a whole language in my BNF, rather, I just want to cover most of the productions that describe the code fragment.  Suggestions would be much appreciated.

BNF so far...

```
<string> ::= …
<number> ::= …
<identifier> ::= …
<assignment> ::= <identifier> = <expression>
<statements> ::=  <statement> <statements>
<statement> ::= <assignment> | <if_statement> | <for_statement> | <while_statement> | …
<expression> ::= <expression> + <term> | <expression> - <term> | <term>
<term> ::= <term> * <factor> | <term> / <factor> | <factor>
<factor> ::= <identifier> | <number> | (<expression)>
<relational_operator>  ::=  < | > | <= | >= | = 
<condition> ::= <expression> <relational_operator>  <expression> 
<if_statement> ::= If <condition> Then <statement>
    | If <condition> Then <statements> End If
    | If <condition> Then <statements> Else <statements> End If
```

Comment: Presumably there's a reason why literals, including string literals, are not   expressions?

Comment: I am trying to ‘join the dots’ between the token stream generated in lexical analysis, which might look something like this... 
[Keyword:If]
[Identifier:Temperature]
[Relational_operator:<=] 
[Number:0] 
[Keyword:Then]
[Identifier:Description]
[Assignment_operator:=]
[Quote:"]
[String_literal:Freezing]
[Quote:"]
[Keyword:End If] ...and the grammar, and a parse tree.  I understand that a lexer would generate separate tokens for quotes and the literal string in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the code sample:

```
X = "hi"
Y = 6 - X
```

The `6 - X` expression is an error, but you can't make it a syntax error using just a context-free grammar. Similarly for:

```
If Temperature <= X Then ...
```

Instead of catching such type errors via the grammar, you'll have to catch them later, either statically or dynamically. And given that you have to do that analysis anyway, there's not much point trying to catch *any* type errors (express any type constraints) in the grammar.

So go with your first solution, adding `<string_literal>` to `<factor>`.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't provide any details about your language, it seems reasonable to believe that a language which has string literals and string variables also has some operations on strings, at least function calls taking strings as arguments and probably certain operators. (In VB, as I understand it, both <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>&</kbd> function as string concatenation operators.)

In that case, assignment to a string variable is not limited to assigning a string literal, and the grammar would be expected to allow expressions including string literals.

It is always tempting to attempt to enforce type coherency in a grammar, on the basis that some type errors (such as `6 - "hi"`) can be detected immediately. But there are many other very similar errors (`6 - HiStringVariable`) which cannot be detected until type deduction (or even until runtime, for dynamic languages). The contortions necessary to do partial type checking during the parse are almost never worth the trouble.

Comment: My feeling was not to worry too much about illegal expressions in BNF for the purposes of building a parse tree; type mismatch problems can be picked up later during semantic analysis.  Do you think I should therefore go with
 <factor> ::= <identifier> | <number> | <string> | (<expression)>
and then define <string_literal> in terms of <string>?

Comment: @drummy I don't see why you need both `<string>` ans `<string_literal>`. Other than that, yes.